# How to transfer a list of element from a screen to another using Kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have some trouble to transfert a list of element, that i get from a file (in the first screen), to the second and third screen.

I have 3 Screen managed by ScreenManager, every screen is in a different file.py and have a file.kv.
This is what my ScreenManager looks like (filename : login.py):

```
from interface1 import Interface1App
from interface2 import Interface2App

class LoginApp(App):
    def build(self):
        manager = ScreenManager()

        #add view login
        manager.add_widget(Login(name='login'))

        # add view 'interface1'
        app = Interface1App()
        app.load_kv()
        interfacen1 = app.build()
        manager.add_widget(interfacen1)

        # add view 'interface2'
        app2 = Interface2App()
        app2.load_kv()
        interfacen2 = app2.build()
        manager.add_widget(interfacen2)

        # add view 'interface3'
        app3 = Interface3App()
        app3.load_kv()
        interfacen3 = app3.build()
        manager.add_widget(interfacen3)

        manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="left")
        return manager
```

In the screen manager login i import all the screens (ex: from interface1 import Interface1App)

In the second file, i put in self.list some data, and use it for that interface (filename : interface1.py):

```
from interface2 import Interface2App
class AllImage(Screen):
    CONTAINER_PNG = os.path.join(AllImage_ROOT, 'images')
    IMAGES_NAMES = [c[:-4] for c in os.listdir(CONTAINER_PNG)]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Screen.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        for im in IMAGES_NAMES:
            if IMAGES_NAMES != None :


                toggleimage = ToggleWithImage(src=im+'.png')
                toggleimage.bind(on_press=  lambda a, im=im:self.onpress_addpage(self.listim, im)) 
                self.layout.add_widget(toggleimage)

    def change_screen(self, x, list): 

        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="left")
        self.manager.current = 'interface2'
        self.manager.get_screen('interface2')
        self.manager.list1 = [1,2,3]


    def backtologin(self):
        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
        self.manager.current = 'login'
        self.manager.get_screen('login')


class Interface1App(App):
    '''The kivy App that runs the main root. All we do is build a AllImage
    widget into the root.'''

    def build(self):

        screen = AllImage()
        screen.name = 'interface1'
        return screen
```

After that i want to use again the data collected in the 2nd interface (self.list) and use it in the 3rd Interface (filename: interace2.py):

```
from interface1 import AllImage #this isn't working
class Combinaison(Screen):


    screen = ObjectProperty(None)    

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # self._previously_parsed_text = ''
        super(Combinaison, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # self.list = list(self.manager.get_screen('interface1').list)
        print(self.manager.list1) # The problem is here <===========


    def backtointerface1(self):
        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
        self.manager.current = 'interface1'
        self.manager.get_screen('interface1')

class Interface2App(App):
    '''The kivy App that runs the main root. All we do is build a Combinaison
    widget into the root.'''

    def build(self):
        screen = Combinaison()
        screen.name = 'interface2'
        return screen
```

With this code i have this error : `print(self.manager.list1)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'list1'`

I think i didn't understand how i should use the self.manager.list1=[1, 2, 3]

I hope that i was clear, sorry for the long post.
Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Screen.manager.get_screen(name).list = list(self.list)`

A complete example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Screen1(Screen):

    list = [1,2,3]

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):

        super(Screen1,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.switch_button = Button(text="goto 2")
        self.switch_button.bind(on_release=self.switch)
        self.add_widget(self.switch_button)

    def switch(self,*args):
        self.list = [4,5,6]
        self.manager.get_screen("screen2").list = list(self.list)
        self.manager.current = "screen2"


class Screen2(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):

        super(Screen2,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.switch_button = Button(text="goto 1")
        self.switch_button.bind(on_release=self.switch)
        self.add_widget(self.switch_button)

    def switch(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = "screen1"

    def on_enter(self):
        print self.list


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):

        sc1 = Screen1(name="screen1")
        sc2 = Screen2(name="screen2")

        self.sm = ScreenManager()

        self.sm.add_widget(sc1)
        self.sm.add_widget(sc2)

        return self.sm


MainApp().run()
```

You can also use the ScreenManager to store the list or lists.

```
self.manager.list1 = [1,2,3] # dont call this in __init__
self.manager.list2 = [4,5,6] # call it in on_enter instead
```

Those lists will be available from all screens after they are added to the manager. The on_enter method on the screen would be suitable for your example.

Comment: @HoussamElkari I will rewrite my example. just a moment

Comment: Hi, do you mean somthink like this : `def __init__(self, **kwargs):` `self._previously_parsed_text = '' super(Combinaison,self).__init__(**kwargs)` `screen1 = self.manager.get_screen('interface1')` `self.list = list(screen1.list)` because this don't work for me, i get this error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'` And knowing that the 2 screens are not in the same windown i can't just use the class name

Comment: Sorry i couldn't edit my comment, that's why i was deleting and adding it again ^^

Comment: @HoussamElkari np. I rewrote my example

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can i use the class Screen1(Screen) if it is not in the same file.py, because you are allowed to import only the class MainApp(App). When i try to import Screen1 i get this error :     from interface1 import AllImage
 ImportError: cannot import name 'AllImage' .

Comment: @HoussamElkari pls pass all the details in your question

Comment: i hope this will help you understand my problem, thank you again for your help

Comment: @HoussamElkari yes. But can you show where you do the imports, and note the respective filenames? :) sry for being demanding.

Comment: Every file contain more than 100 lines that's why i copy only the necessary parts ^^ thanks again @EL3PHANTEN

Comment: @HoussamElkari thats allright.. I just got confused by the title of the question. This is more like a question about debugging you import error, than passing a list. Am I right?

Comment: Actually u didn't understand wrong what the title ment to say, it's just that i tried what u told me and it gave me this error : `self.manager.get_screen('interface2').list = list(self.list)
 TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

I have the same error when i use self.manager.list1 = [1,2,3]

Comment: @HoussamElkari `self.manager.list1 = [1,2,3]` should not give that error. Dont call it before the screen is added to the manager

Comment: Sorry to bother you again ^^' i have edited my question with the self.manager.list1 and how i did use it @EL3PHANTEN

Comment: @HoussamElkari the problemis that you call it within the initiation of the Screen. They are only initiated once. You should call it `on_enter`

Comment: Oh, i didn't know what was do_enter before !! now that i tried it and see it's use, it resolve all my problems !! Thank you very much @EL3PHANTEN for understanding my problem and giving me your time. Thank you again !! :D

Comment: @HoussamElkari you are very wellcome :)

Comment: Hello dear @EL3PHANTEN, sorry to bother u again but i am a little in trouble. If u have some time, look at my problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400142/encountring-an-error-with-videos-kivy-on-windows-7

I hope that u have an idea of where the source of the problem is. Thank you ^^