# Encountring an error with videos - Kivy on Windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, kivy, kivy-language

I want to make an application with Kivy that can manipulate videos, my problem is that i can't play videos when i am using kivy, my operating system is Windows7.

In the demo example given with Kivy, here is the result :

[image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zSNzUAfohA]

in this youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zSNzUAfohA), in minute 1h18min30sec the video is actually working

The result i had before was this picture :

[image: The grid contain 4 videos, no one is working, but i have no error so my code must be fine]

I hope u guys know what is the problem source.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: seems that the file doesn't exist...

Comment: last time i messed with video in kivy the audio would consistently get out of synch with the video ... I finally gave up on kivy+video (to be fair it was probably some codec issue or something) ... but good luck to you

Comment: Thanks for your answers, @Jean-François Fabre in my application, the video exist, and i tried the same code with Image instead, it's woring fine, I also tried the Example given in KivyCatalog i will edit the result in a minute in this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `kivy.deps.gstreamer` if you don't have it yet. Catalog should then work.

The second image looks like you have non-existing files included.

Comment: Thank you verry much @KeyWeeUsr, it worked, and i figured out where my other problem came from.